Terminal running SSH freezes after unlocking screen
On my MacBook (Sequoia 15.1), I often have an SSH (OpenSSH 9.8p1) session open in my terminal.  However, when I lock and unlock my screen, the terminal becomes completely unresponsive.  No key strokes are recognized and I have no choice but to close the terminal window and reconnect in a new terminal.
How do I fix/prevent this?

Can you still open a new tab in Terminal?

If you press ~ Enter (that is, press tilde and Enter at the same time), can you exit the SSH session? In System Settings > Battery, if you press Options…, is "Prevent automatic sleeping on power adapter when the display is off" turned off?

Have you seen this? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36690/how-can-i-prevent-an-ssh-session-from-hanging-in-os-x-terminal?rq=1

@jaume: Yeah, that exits the session.  That option is turned off.

@nohillside: Yes, I can still open new tabs.

Maybe the network connection gets lost during the Lock Screen phase. With a new tab open, you can kill the hanging ssh. This at least avoids the restart.

Thank you for your feedback. I have the impression your Mac goes to sleep when the screen is locked, if your turn the option on, does it solve the problem?

@jaume, nothing changed.
